# Can you disable certain breakpoints in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm about to start using bootstrap for a project and only wanted to have 2 breakpoints enabled.

Essentially I only really want my website to have 2 'modes', one for xs-min, and the other being around the md-min size.

Is there any way to disable specific breakpoints?

Comment: Related: http://milos.gavrilovic.rs/how-to-disable-certain-breakpoints-in-bootstrap-3/

Comment: Yes...go in and delete the appropriate media query.

Comment: There is not need to delete anything. There are four .col-xx classes (3 breakpoints) you can use, col-xs, col-sm, col-md, col-lg. Simply code your pages using the two that you would like to have. Modifying anything more than this completely negates the use for the using Bootstrap in the first place and can become problematic the more tweaks you start applying. 

Further, Bootstrap actually needs 3 breakpoints for most scenarios as while the grid is percentage-based, it uses a lot of fixed pixel units throughout the framework (as opposed to more fluid units, such as %, em, etc.)